# Not sure how to create a custom Iterator nested class for my implementation of a User class for a social network

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to implement a nested iterator class for a User class for a school project. I am not sure how to go about creating the iterator subclass, and how I can make it work with my parent class.

The user is supposed to be apart of a Social Network, and I am having trouble implementing a way to have this user have a "Friends List".

The rules are, you are not allowed to change anything in the header file provided by the instructor, however, you can add whatever methods and fields you want to the header class, and all of the provided methods need to be implemented.

The header file is shown below:

```
class User
{
public:
    using ID = size_t;

    //! What is this user's ID?
    ID id() const;

    //! How many friends does this user have?
    size_t degree() const;

    //! Set name of this User
    void setName(std::string name);

    //! Make this User friends with another User.
    void addFriend(const User&);


    //! An iterator that can iterate over all of a User's friends
    struct FriendIterator
    {
        User& operator*();
        FriendIterator operator ++ (int);

        bool operator == (const FriendIterator&) const;
        bool operator != (const FriendIterator&) const;

    };

    //! Get an iterator that will iterate over this User's friends
    FriendIterator begin() const;

    //! Get an iterator that signifies the end of any friend iteration.
    FriendIterator end() const;

private:
};
```

So far, this is what I have added to the private section of the header file:

```
    std::vector<User> friends_;
    std::string name_;

    ID uID_ = generateID();
    ID generateID();
```

And I have implemented all of the methods besides the Begin and End FriendIterator methods as well as the Friend Iterator Structure.

```
#include "User.h"

void User::addFriend(const User& buddy)
{
    friends_.push_back(buddy);
}

void User::setName(std::string name)
{
    name_ = name;
}

size_t User::degree() const
{
    return friends_.size();
}

User::ID User::generateID()
{
    static ID newID{ 0 };
    return newID++;
}
User::ID User::id() const
{
    return uID_;
}
```

I was wondering how I could go about implementing the begin and end friendIterator methods, as well as the friendIterator structure itself.

Comment: `std::vector<User>` within `User` definition is undefined behaviour because `User` is not complete yet and endlessly recursive. You probably need `std::vector<User*>`.

Comment: I see! My only issue with what your saying is how I would go about re-implementing my addFriend method, as it takes in a const User&, which I am unable to take a pointer of I think...

Comment: You can take a pointer given a reference. May need to add `const`: `std::vector<User const*>`.

Comment: I see. Do you know of a way I can assign a shared_ptr to the function void User::addFriend(const User& buddy) and then add that to a vector of shared ptrs that point to const Users? Basically the same thing you suggested except instead of a raw pointer, I would like to use a shared_ptr